# Python can't find file in Windows Subsystem for Linux

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I wrote a script using python in the Ubuntu environment in WSL.

I downloaded firebase's private key "serviceAccountKey.json" in Windows, and then moved it to my working directory in wsl. (using 'mv mnt/c/Users/Yiu/Downloads/serviceAccountKey.json ~/projects/scrape'). Now, I'm trying to pass that file to the Certificate() but I get a file not found error.

I did a bit of research and found out there could some issues with the permissions, but the file all read, write and execute permissions.

The script:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials, firestore

cred = credentials.Certificate("~/projects/scrape/serviceAccountKey.json")
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)
db = firestore.client()
```

How can I get rid of the file not found error?

Comment: Is your path correct?

Comment: Do you check which `python` you run? In WSL you may occasionally run Windows `python`, and it just does not understand path with ~.

Comment: Yes, my path is correct

Comment: How can I check which python I'm running?

Comment: `> which python`

Comment: usr/bin/python is what I get

Comment: The python seems correct. If you use absolute full path instead of `~/projects/scrape/serviceAccountKey.json`, does it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the absolute path, since the `~` will be different by the calling user in

```
cred = credentials.Certificate("~/projects/scrape/serviceAccountKey.json")
```

Comment: How do you use the absolute path? In my case it is \\wsl$\debian\home\u which does not work in python, cannot find the path with \.

Answer (score 1):

`~` is normally expanded by the shell to the value of `$HOME`. That doesn't apply to paths in your programs, including Python programs, unless they also do similar substitutions; Python provides utilities for this in [pathlib.Path.expanduser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.expanduser) and [os.path.expanduser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser).